# How to access unique product ids with session arrays

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have this index.php page which is displaying all my products from the database.

Currently the products on index.php is being displayed through a while loop:

```
<?php
// Getting data fra DB and fetching the $result as an array
$product_id = -1; // Counter
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Products;");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$altname = strtr($row[Product_Name], '-', ' ');
$altcolor = strtr($row[Product_Color], '-', ' ');
$altcat = strtr($row[Product_Category], '-', ' ');
$_SESSION['product_id'] = $row['Product_Id']++;

?>




<?php

$excerpt = $row['Product_Desc'];
$maxLength = 150;

if (strlen($excerpt) > $maxLength) {
    $stringCut = substr($excerpt, 0, $maxLength);
    $excerpt = substr($stringCut, 0, strrpos($stringCut, ' '));
}
echo "<div class='col-md-4 col-xs-6 hero-feature productview'>";
echo "<div class='thumbnail'>";
echo "<img class='img-responsive' src=\"image/$row[Product_Img]\" alt=\"$altname $altcolor $altcat\" >";
echo "<div class='caption'>";
echo "<h3>" . $row['Product_Name'] . "</h3>";
echo "<p>" . $excerpt . "..." . "</p>";
echo "<p><a href='#' class='btn btn-primary'>Køb nu!</a>";
echo "<a href='product.php?id=$_SESSION[product_id]' class='btn btn-default'>Se produktet</a></p>";
echo "</div></div></div>";
} ?>
```

And in the loop we have added an a href which should link to the Product.php page which is the site that contain much more info on the unique Product_Id retrieved from the DB.

The main issue is that when in the while loop the $_SESSION['product_id'] is looping correctly, but when I try to var_dump outside of the loop it just takes the last item in the session array (this is what happens on the product.php page).

How can I get the session array in an a href to loop correct on each unique product page.

Comment: ... That's because you are overriding the `$_SESSION['product_id']` each time you run through the loop, you'd need to store it in a array like so `$_SESSION['product_id'][]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However I get this error: Fatal error: [] operator not supported for strings in index.php on line 37
Which is this one: $_SESSION['product_id'][] = $row['Product_Id']++;

Comment: Outside (before) the loop : $_SESSION['product_id'] = array(); Inside the loop : $_SESSION['product_id'] []= $row['Product_Id']++;

Comment: In fact the $_SESSION['product_id'] = array(); outside the loop can even be left out

Comment: Sorry, but my output is just an Array then. Am I supposed to put a value into the $_SESSION['product_id'] []?

Comment: Okay, so I managed to solve it with your help by accessing the product_id from each product in the DB from the url with $_GET['id'], since the loop worked on the index.php. Thanks.